# how to convert json data item into variable?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am working on Json data which is coming from television api. From this api i want to use "tvshow.episode.ratings.loved" value. how can i link this value to something like
$scope.like = tvshow.episode.ratings.loved; i want to do some math operations with this. how can i convert this lengthy json text into $scope.like? where should i include it in my code? pls help

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp',[]);

app.controller("mainController", function ($scope, $http, $filter){

    $scope.filteredItems = [];       

    $scope.pagedItems = [];
    $scope.curPage = 1;

     $scope.init = function() {

        $http.jsonp('http://api.trakt.tv/calendar/premieres.json/' + $scope.apiKey + '/' + apiDate + '/' + 30 + '/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(data) {

            angular.forEach(data, function(value, index){


                angular.forEach(value.episodes, function(tvshow, index){
                    tvshow.date = date; 
                    $scope.results.push(tvshow);
                    angular.forEach(tvshow.show.genres, function(genre, index){
                        //Only add to the availableGenres array if it doesn't already exist
                        var exists = false;
                        angular.forEach($scope.availableGenres, function(avGenre, index){
                            if (avGenre == genre) {
                                exists = true;
                            }
                        });

                    });

                });
            });                  
            };  


        }).error(function(error) {

        });
    };

    app.$inject = ($scope, $filter);



});
```

Comment: I order to help you properly, we'd need to know what the JSON looks like ;)

Comment: http://api.trakt.tv/calendar/premieres.json/982db1c71a81fffd5d1a582b094c07b2

Comment: PS. you generally don't want to post your API keys publicly.

Comment: @jValdron -no problem it's tv schedule. anyone can register in it.

Answer (score 3):

After

```
$scope.groupedItems = [];
```

Add

```
$scope.loved = [];
```

And in this loop add

```
 angular.forEach(value.episodes, function(tvshow, index) {
      // .... code
    $scope.loved.push(tvshow.ratings.loved);
})
```

If you want just show rating for each item, you need add in you template this

```
<span class="label"><i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i> {{tvshow.show.ratings.loved}}</span> 
<span class="label"><i class="icon-thumbs-down"></i> {{tvshow.show.ratings.hated}}</span>
```

In result you get array with all "loved rating"